# How do I add a project to CruiseControl.NET?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I am looking at the cruisecontrol web dashboard. I can see one farm and one server. However, I don't see any way to add a project?

Is this something I can do with the UI or do I need to edit the config file by hand?

Comment: If you're wanting web UI-based management, you might want to evaluate TeamCity. http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/index.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to edit the `ccnet.config` file by hand (located within the CruiseControl directory) to add projects. There are some graphical tools to help you do this however you do get used to doing it by hand fairly quickly - just have the documentation near by!

Update: An example of one such tool is http://www.codeplex.com/ccnetconfig

Comment: You can also download CCValidator to validate your changes. You wouldn't want a busy CC machine to tell you your changes suck, and then wait for the current build to end before finding out if you fixed it properly or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CCNETConfig](http://www.codeplex.com/ccnetconfig) to edit the config file through an UI although it doesn't support higher version > CruiseControl.NET 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

You have to basically edit the configuration file by hand, however I have it setup so that the raw config file is split into different include files, each of which is setup in my source control system. Then I created a project for the configuration, and then for the whole config. So when something changes in the config, CC.NET itself pulls out the changes, recreates it's config files and the refreshes the system configuration.

This means that anyone can edit the config (if they can access the files in sourcecontrol), and no-one has to go into the program files directory of the CC.NET machine itself.

Not sure whether this answers the question you asked, but this is how our setup works